# I get a different accuracy each time I run a classifier on my data

Tags: classification, cross-validation, noise

I'm trying to perform binary classification on a data (80 sample data points, 39542 predictor dimensions). The data contain 2 classes, one in 18 samples and the other one in 62 samples.

I split my data into training, validation, and test samples, but each time I run the classifier it gets a different result, e.g., 0.87, 0.83, 0.70, or even sometimes 0.50. I tried SVM or DT - both give almost the same result.

What does this indicate? Does this mean my data is noisy? Is there any way that I can stabilize my result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split your sample in different ways, then your classifier will get different training and validation data in each case and therefore classify the test data in different ways. (Plus, it will get different test data in each case.)

You have very little data and very many predictors. In such a case, your classification variance will necessarily be large, so re-running your classifier on different training and validation sets will yield classifications that differ a lot.

I'd recommend either getting (a lot) more data, or regularizing in some way.

Incidentally, re-running your classification to see how much it varies is an *excellent* idea. You are learning a lot about your data and your problem in this way!